# Java Graphics: Passing Parameters to the paint method

Tags: java, graphics, parameters, paint

In this example I'm trying to create a dice. To do this I want to pass a random value between 1 and 6 from my updateVal method into my paint method, however I'm not sure how to pass parameters into the paint method.

Currently I'm using the repaint method which obviously you can't pass parameters through.

```
public void updateVal(int i){
    repaint();
} 

public void paint(Graphics g, int rollValue){
    super.paint(g);

    int value = rollValue;
    switch (value) {
        case 1:  g.fillOval(200, 200, 100, 100);
                 break;
        case 2:  g.fillOval(350, 50, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(50, 450, 100, 100);
                 break;
        case 3:  g.fillOval(350, 50, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(200, 250, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(50, 450, 100, 100);
                 break;
        case 4:  g.fillOval(350, 50, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(50, 350, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(50, 50, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(350, 350, 100, 100);
                 break;
        case 5:  g.fillOval(350, 50, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(50, 350, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(50, 50, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(350, 350, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(200, 200, 100, 100);
        break;
        case 6:  g.fillOval(350, 50, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(50, 350, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(50, 50, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(350, 350, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(50, 200, 100, 100);
                 g.fillOval(350, 200, 100, 100);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a member variable to the `Canvas` you are using, create a setter and set it before calling the `paint()` method:

```
private int rollValue;

public void setRollValue(int val) { this.rollValue = val; }

public void paint(Graphics g) {
  super.paint(g);

  switch (rollValue) {
  ...
  }
}

public void updateVal(int i){
  setRollValue(i);
  repaint();
}
```